# Creating a fixed distance buffer from a virtual layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, virtual-layer

First off, i'm trying to learn some python to automate scripts for basic tasks i carry out in QGIS (2.18).

Below I create a virtual layer (polyline) using the following script:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import * 

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("?query=SELECT cm_code, cm_ndcode1 as 'nd_1', cm_ndcode2 as 'nd_2', COUNT() as 'Num CM', geometry FROM t_cheminement GROUP BY   cm_ndcode1, cm_ndcode2 HAVING   COUNT() > 1" , "CM_DUBLONS", "virtual" )

props = { 'width' : '3', 'color' : '255,0,0' } sl=QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props) s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl])

vlayer.setRendererV2(QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ))
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The above code works fine - but next I want to create a fixed distance buffer around the polylines.

I started off with this:

```
qgis_fixeddistancebuffer(input = CM_DUBLONS, output = 'c:/SIG_DEV_MODEL/buffer_test.shp', distance = 1000)
```

But it returns the error message below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "< input >", line 1, in
>    NameError: name 'qgis_fixeddistancebuffer' is not defined

I've also tried

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', CM_DUBLONS, 500, 6, dissolve, "C:/SIG/SIG_DEV_MODEL/CM_buf2.shp")
```

but likewise I get a similar error message "'processing' is not defined"

I'm probably missing something simple...

Otherwise I've since looked up the following:

[Pyqgis Fixed Buffer Creation in Meters with Haversine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274542/pyqgis-fixed-buffer-creation-in-meters-with-haversine)

and

[How to create dissolved buffer layer with pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259530/how-to-create-dissolved-buffer-layer-with-pyqgis)

But it's not quite what I'm looking for, and I'm not sure how to adapt the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of my answer but ... did u try something like :
`import processing` ?

Comment: If you're not sure or can not provide further information, why your solution should work, rather post a comment than an answer ;-)

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, honestly not sure if it worked or not, but I've got a new error message in anycase! 'Processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 'CM_DUBLONS', 500, 6, dissolve = false, "C:/SIG/SIG_DEV_MODEL/CM_buf2.shp") File "<input>", line 1 SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg'

Comment: i think there must be an issue with your **dissolve** argument. i tried the following :

`import processing` then
`processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 'cities', 500, 20, 'true', "D:/test.shp")`

which ran perfectly.

Try O/1 or 'true'/'false' that should work ...

Comment: So ? Are you still stuck on your problem ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - the bug was with the dissolve arguement - Everything seems to work fine now! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

So thanks to snaileater I've managed to sort the script out - the final script is as below:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=SELECT cm_ndcode1 as 'nd_1', cm_ndcode2 as 'nd_2', COUNT() as 'Num CM', geometry FROM t_cheminement GROUP BY cm_ndcode1, cm_ndcode2 HAVING COUNT() > 1" , "CM_DUBLONS", "virtual" )
props = { 'width' : '3', 'color' : '255,0,0' }
sl = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl])
vlayer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 'CM_DUBLONS', 100, 6, 'true', "C:/XXX/XXXX/XXX/XXXXX/CM_PARA.shp")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(vlayer)
layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/XXX/XXXX/XXX/XXXXX/CM_PARA.shp", "CM_PARA", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```